# Proper, if any, way to use dd as pipe buffer?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, dd, pipe

## The Question

When I looked for pipe buffering tools in *NIX, I see suggestions of using `buffer`, `mbuffer`, or `pv`. However, the former two are not always in distros' official repo (such as Arch), while `pv` (as of 1.6.0) has a bug which prevents this functionality. In a few other questions, I see mentions about `dd` used as buffers, and I would like to explore it because `dd` is always there. However, none are elaborate enough to make real sense, so here I ask for a "proper" way to use it.

Questions mentioned `dd` include https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345072/can-dd-be-used-to-add-a-buffer-to-a-pipe and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21918/utility-to-buffer-an-unbounded-amount-of-data-in-a-pipeline

For ease of testing, I provide a test script below, with some comments about my own experiments. Details will be explained after the code listing. Please make sure you have `pv` installed and at least 256M memory before running!

```
#!/bin/sh

producer() {
    while [ 1 ]; do
    dd if=/dev/zero bs=64M count=1 iflag=fullblock status=none
    sleep 4
    done
}

buffer() {
    # Works, but long
    # Must at least fill 32M before consumer starts
    # So, must choose small obs and chain more to look
    # more like a proper "buffer"
    dd obs=32M status=none | \
        dd obs=32M status=none| \
        dd obs=32M status=none| \
        dd obs=32M status=none
    # Doesn't work, producer rate limited
    #dd bs=128M status=none 
    # Doesn't work, producer must fill buffer, then
    # must wait until buffer is empty
    #dd obs=128M status=none 
    # Doesn't work, producer rate limited
    #dd ibs=128M status=none 
    # Doesn't work, producer must fill buffer, then
    # must wait until buffer is empty
    #dd bs=128M status=none iflag=fullblock
}

consumer() {
    pv --rate-limit 1M -q | dd of=/dev/null status=none
}

producer | pv -cN produce | buffer | pv -cN consume | consumer
```

Here, the producer produces 64MB of data every 4 seconds, with a 128MB buffer, while the consumer consumes at a constant 1MB/s rate. Of course, this means that buffer will overflow pretty quick, but this is to show effects clearly. Ideally, before buffer fills up (at the third production), we should see a constant 1MB/s consumption, and bursts of production giving 64MB data each. The "correct" output looks like this:

```
  produce:  128MiB 0:00:07 [   0 B/s] [  <=>                                                       ]
  consume: 7.25MiB 0:00:07 [1.01MiB/s] [       <=>                                                 ]
```

Here, the working solution is shown as following:

```
dd obs=32M status=none | \
    dd obs=32M status=none| \
    dd obs=32M status=none| \
    dd obs=32M status=none
```

This is constructed by splitting the required 128MB buffer into 4 chunks. Yes, each chunk must fill up before data is passed to next level, but since 32MB is smaller than the 64MB burst, it works for this test, as if it is a real buffer. Now, there are some problems.

1. In real applications, we don't have an instantaneous burst of data, so chunks need to be small, but not *too* small. Which means there will be a long chain of `dd` commands
2. <del>What if an EOF is encountered, before 32MB mark is reached? Will that block be lost?</del> I tested with `dd if=test.txt| dd obs=1M | dd obs=1M | dd of=test2.txt` and compared result. Turns out that this is not a problem. So, using it for backup won't corrupt data.
3. How much overhead does it create?
4. Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same, by cleverly arranging parameters?

There are a few other attempts included in the script, and they don't work, as explained in comments. And I have tried using FIFO + background processes, which yields the same result.

PS. Just so you know, buffering a pipe is quite useful when backing up A into B, especially when A is a HDD, which has seek time. So I would do something like this:

```
tar cSpf - <path> -C <root path> | <a large buffer> | <some parallel compressor> \
| <small buffer if compressor is generally slow and B have seek time> \
| dd bs=<several GB if B is not an SSD> iflag=fullblock oflag=direct of=<archive.tar.??>
```

Comment: To chain identical commands you can use recursive function, e.g. `buf() { if [ "$2" -gt 0 ] ; then dd status=none obs="$1" | buf "$1" $(($2-1)) ; else cat ; fi ; }`. Usage: `producer | buf 32M 4 | consumer`.

Comment: That sounds better, definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am putting in my own answer. It might not be the best, but it is OK.

## Caution

This is written in front after many tests.

**Do not chain too many DD's for buffering, or all your CPU cores may block on IO, and your computer will freeze even if you have tons of memory left!**

Especially toxic if you have some broken slow external USB drive which also needs ridiculous IO intensity to read/write.

## Examples

I basically exhausted all combinations of DD options. A single DD seems to be impossible for this task, since it cannot perform asynchronous IO. Otherwise, in the chain of DD-buffer, the largest block must be filled before it starts to act like a FIFO. So, if you don't care about initial delay when filling the pipe... A chain of two dd's work. I hope someone else can provide a more elegant solution, but here is an example usage.

*Example 1*: Tarring all files from a heavily fragmented HDD A (response time jitters) to a heavily fragmented HDD B (jitters), using XZ as compression algorithm (slow) in parallel (jitters if you are actually using the computer) (disclaimer: I am writing this from my head, so minor details might be wrong. Use at your own risk):

```
tar -cpSf - -C /mnt/A . | \
  dd obs=1024M | dd obs=1024M | \
  xz -T 0 -c | \
  dd obs=1024M | dd obs=1024M | \
  dd bs=512M iflag=fullblock of=/mnt/B/A.tar.xz
```

Add `pv` to see speed. Here, `xz` starts only after 1GB data is read from A(unless it has less than 1GB, then it finishes). Similarly, disk writing to B starts only after 1GB data comes out from xz. This code gives 2GB buffer between `tar` and `xz`, and 2GB between `xz` and writing. The `bs=512M` at the end is not really necessary, but I found a large (>64M) block size gives a better average writing speed, especially on USB hard drives. I suppose it creates less fragments, too, if drive B is in use (not confirmed).

*Example 2*. Objective: copy a gigantic file from a heavily fragmented disk A to a heavily fragmented disk B.

```
dd if=/mnt/A/file obs=<half of cache you want> | dd bs=<half of cache> iflag=fullblock oflag=direct of=/mnt/B/file
```

This is one of the simplest form I can find. If the file is gigantic enough, the initial time used to fill the cache should be negligible. Meanwhile, it reads/writes asynchronously, and hopefully groups enough writes together to get some sequential performance. I suppose SSD's won't care about block size, though.

*Example 3*. Thanks to Kamil Maciorowski, I now have the following in my `.zshrc`:

```
buffer() {
    if [ "$2" -gt 0 ] ; then
        dd status=none obs="$1" | buffer "$1" $(($2-1))
    else 
        cat 
    fi
}
```

Now, if you need 3 blocks of 512M buffer, chain `buffer 512M 3` in your pipeline. Generally, if your job is large enough for your throughput (eg. Copying/Compressing 100GB+ data @ 100MB/s on average), a smaller block gives no advantage other than filling the pipe more quickly (which is irrelevant since this time is small). I have observed that if you put in too many blocks, the CPU might be so busy on IO that the command freezes the entire computer.

Now, Example 1 becomes

```
tar -cpSf - -C /mnt/A . | \
buffer 1024M 2 | \
xz -T 0 -c | \
buffer 1024M 2 | \
dd bs=512M iflag=fullblock of=/mnt/B/A/tar.xz
```