# Why are read / write sequential and not parallel?

Tags: hard-drive, dd

I copy data from one disc to other

```
sudo dd status=progress if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdd ibs=1G obs=1G
```

But I notice that read/write are done sequential:

[image]

[image]

**Is there a way to make it parallel to speed up coping?**

Comment: If you reduce your block sizes to something more sensible (like 1M) then you will be able to make better use of disk write caches and it will probably look more parallel.

Comment: @Mokubai: probably it will look parallel, but will not parallel. Besides disk clone process becomes more slower. Now average speed is 126MB/s, will smaller buffer it is 18MB/s

Comment: Related https://superuser.com/questions/1206127/proper-if-any-way-to-use-dd-as-pipe-buffer

Comment: Also, rather suprisingly, an assertion that `cat` may actually be faster than `dd` for some reason https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322274/483098

Comment: Parallel to what? Can you write words to paper in "parallel"? How do you guarantee that the expected order of data is maintained?  ***Or is this just a XY question, and the real issue is how to speed up a copy?***

Comment: @sawdust: while one buffer is writing to disk, we can read from second HDD into other buffer in parallel. How to speed up copy is another question ;-)

Comment: If that is what you meant, then you should have written a better question with that information included. There's a hardware dependency to your scheme: if the two storage drives share an interface (i.e. SATA) controller, then two concurrent operations (one on each drive) may not be possible.  FYI "concurrent" is the better word to use than *"parallel"*.  Your specification of an outrageous block size is also counterproductive.

Comment: About speed: https://itnext.io/modern-storage-is-plenty-fast-it-is-the-apis-that-are-bad-6a68319fbc1a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case is using multiple disks.

The program is single-buffering.

It needs to use double (or multiple) buffering.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer

Comment: is it really `dd` single buffering? I seems strange for so old unix utility to have such disadvantage ((

Comment: Well, I don't have the source code available to me (but its out there). I think its a fair bet that because it is so old that it likely is single buffering.  Even today a lot of people code  
`code`  
OPEN INPUT  
OPEN OUTPUT  
DO WHILE RECORDS 
   READ INPUT  
  WRITE OUTPUT  
END LOOP

Answer (score -2):

When it comes to hard disk drives, there are a number of heads but as they are all statically mounted to one arm they can't be used independently. So there is no way to speed up transfers.